# How to do a single line If statement in VBScript for Classic-ASP?

Tags: if-statement, syntax, vbscript, asp-classic

The "single line if statement" exists in C# and VB.NET as in many other programming and script languages in the following format

```
lunchLocation = (dayOfTheWeek == "Tuesday") ? "Fuddruckers" : "Food Court";
```

does anyone know if there is even in VBScript and what's the extact syntax?

Comment: Looks like it might not be built into the language, take a look at this: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t041301-1.shtml edit - This looks like better information actually - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219271

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The conditional ternary operator doesn't exist out of the box, but it's pretty easy to create your own version in VBScript:

```
Function IIf(bClause, sTrue, sFalse)
    If CBool(bClause) Then
        IIf = sTrue
    Else 
        IIf = sFalse
    End If
End Function
```

You can then use this, as per your example:

```
lunchLocation = IIf(dayOfTheWeek = "Tuesday", "Fuddruckers", "Food Court")
```

The advantage of this over using a single line `If`/`Then`/`Else` is that it can be directly concatenated with other strings. Using `If`/`Then`/`Else` on a single line must be the only statement on that line.

There is no error checking on this, and the function expects a well formed expression that can be evaluated to a boolean passed in as the clause. For a more complicated and comprehensive answer see below. Hopefully this simple response neatly demonstrates the logic behind the answer though.

It's also worth noting that unlike a real ternary operator, **both the `sTrue` and `sFalse` parameters will be evaluated regardless of the value of `bClause`**. This is fine if you use it with strings as in the question, but be very careful if you pass in functions as the second and third parameters!

Comment: I can't imagine why one would complicate code in such a way ..

Comment: I can't imagine why VBScript was ever created

Comment: I can't imagine why someone would be commenting in a VBScript question if he hates the language so much.

Comment: @MikeQ I can't imagine how it would not be obvious to someone who pretends to be a developper that 1 line of code is more readable than 5.

Comment: This is also useful if you need to reuse (copy) VB6 or VBA code into VBScript.

Comment: @Virus721 the code feels needless and gross, someone has to parse out every time what is going on, IIF is also a poor description and I would assume you are someone who writes code without comment because "it's self explainatory".

Answer (score 21):

VBScript does not have any ternary operator.
A close solution in a single line and without using a user defined function, pure VBScript:

```
If dayOfTheWeek = "Tuesday" Then lunchLocation = "Fuddruckers" Else lunchLocation = "Food Court"
```

BTW, you can use JScript in Classic ASP if ternary opertor is so important to you.

Answer (score 15):

**edited** 2017/01/28 to adapt to some of the non boolean condition arguments

*Note*: If all you need is to select an string based on an boolean value, please, use the code in the Polinominal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20353438/2861476). It is simpler and faster than the code in this answer.

For a simple but more *"flexible"* solution, this code (the original code in this answer) should handle the usual basic scenarios

```vbs
Function IIf( Expression, TruePart, FalsePart)
Dim bExpression
    bExpression = False 
    On Error Resume Next
    bExpression = CBool( Expression )
    On Error Goto 0
    If bExpression Then 
        If IsObject(TruePart) Then 
            Set IIf = TruePart
        Else 
            IIf = TruePart
        End If 
    Else
        If IsObject(FalsePart) Then 
            Set IIf = FalsePart
        Else 
            IIf = FalsePart
        End If 
    End If 
End Function
```

If uses the `Cbool` function to try to convert the passed `Expression` argument to a boolean, and accepts any type of value in the `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` arguments. For general usage this is fast, safe and fully complies to documented VBScript behaviour.

The only *"problem"* with this code is that the behaviour of the `CBool` is not fully *"intuitive"* for some data types, at least for those of us that constantly change between vbscript and javascript. While numeric values are coherent (a `0` is a `False` and any other numeric value is a `True`), non numeric types generate a runtime error (in previous code handled as false), except if it is a string with numeric content or that can be interpreted as true or false value in english or in the OS locale.

If you **need** it, a VBScript version *"equivalent"* to the `?` javascript ternary operator is

```vbs
Function IIf( Expression, TruePart, FalsePart )
Dim vType, bExpression 

    vType = VarType( Expression )
    Select Case vType
        Case vbBoolean                : bExpression = Expression 
        Case vbString                 : bExpression = Len( Expression ) > 0
        Case vbEmpty, vbNull, vbError : bExpression = False
        Case vbObject                 : bExpression = Not (Expression Is Nothing)
        Case vbDate, vbDataObject     : bExpression = True
        Case Else
            If vType > 8192 Then 
                bExpression = True
            Else
                bExpression = False 
                On Error Resume Next
                bExpression = CBool( Expression )
                On Error Goto 0
            End If 
    End Select 

    If bExpression Then 
        If IsObject( TruePart ) Then 
            Set IIf = TruePart
        Else 
            IIf = TruePart
        End If 
    Else
        If IsObject( FalsePart ) Then 
            Set IIf = FalsePart
        Else 
            IIf = FalsePart
        End If 
    End If 
End Function
```

BUT independently of the version used, be careful, **you are calling a function, not using a ternary operator**. Any code, or function call you put in TruePart of FalsePart WILL BE EXECUTED independently of the value of the condition. So this code

```
value = IIf( 2 > 3 , DoSomething(), DontDoSomething() )
```

WILL EXECUTE the two functions. Only the correct value will be returned to `value` var.

Comment: Very handy "be careful" note. Was wondering why on earth my script was appearing to be going against logic.

Answer (score 6):

There's a weird trick possible (hi, Python!) for exact one-liner:

```
lunchLocation = array("Food Court", "Fuddruckers")(-(dayOfTheWeek = "Tuesday"))
```

The "magic" works because of a boolean operation specifics in VBScript. 
*True* is actually -1 and *False* is 0, therefore we can use it as an index for array (just get rid of a minus). Then the first item of array will be a value for False condition and second item for True.

Answer (score 3):

related to @MC_ND answer:

to execute only one function, you can do something like that:

```
If VarType(TruePart) = vbString and InStr(1,TruePart,"function:") = 1 then
  IIf = GetRef(Mid(TruePart,10))()
Else
  IIf = TruePart
End If
```

the same for the FalsePart, and call IIf() it like that:

```
value = IIf( 2 > 3 , "function:DoSomething", "function:DontDoSomething" )
```

and will call DoSomething() or DontDoSomething()