# Calculations in ASP Classic and FormatNumber the result

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

After my previous post (in which everyone was really helpful - thanks) ive now hit another issue... Calculations and to FormatNumber the result.

I have 3 fields in SQL that i need to do a simple calculation with then the result needs to have FormatNumber applied to it..

the fields are

"OverallFee" , "WIPFee" , "RenderedFee" - all are numeric

throughout the table they populate fine with the below.

```
<td width="100" align="center" class="style1"><% If Not IsNull(rs("OverallFee")) Then Response.Write ("£" + FormatNumber(rs("OverallFee"),0)) End If %></td>
<td width="100" align="center" class="style1"><% If Not IsNull(rs("RenderedFee")) Then Response.Write ("£" + FormatNumber(rs("RenderedFee"),0)) End If %></td>
<td width="100" align="center" class="style1"><%=rs("WIPFee")%></td>
```

Now I need to do a calculation -

```
("OverallFee"/100) * "WIPFee" - "RenderedFee"
```

I've tried

```
<td width="50" align="center" class="style1"><%=((rs("OverallFee")/100)*rs("WIPFee")-rs("RenderedFee"))%></td>
```

It should work but I'm getting

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' - Type mismatch "

on that line and I'm stuck...

Am I doing it right... is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert your data to long `CLng` or double `CDbl`

```
<%
    calc = 0 'Or a text to display

    If Not IsNull(rs("RenderedFee")) And Not IsNull(rs("OverallFee")) And Not IsNull(rs("WIPFee")) Then
        calc = (CLng(rs("OverallFee"))/100)*CLng(rs("WIPFee"))-CLng(rs("RenderedFee"))
    End If
%>

<td width="50" align="center" class="style1"><%=calc%></td>
```

Comment: Are you sure that OverallFee, WIPFee, RenderedFee are always numbers ?

Comment: i need to add - "If Not IsNull" somehow

Comment: Tried - <% If Not IsNull((CLng(rs("OverallFee"))/100)*CLng(rs("WIPFee"))-CLng(rs("RenderedFee"))) Then Response.Write ("£" + FormatNumber((CLng(rs("OverallFee"))/100)*CLng(rs("WIPFee"))-CLng(rs("RenderedFee"))),0)%> - no good

Comment: It's not `"£" + FormatNumber` but `"£" & FormatNumber`

Comment: @krlzlx Actually both `+` and `&` work as string concatenation operators. I personally prefer `&` though.

Comment: sorry @krlzlx- on the FormatNumber of calc - ive tried `<%=("£" + FormatNumber(calc)),0)%>` but to no avail - "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub"

Comment: Isn't it: <%=("£" + FormatNumber(calc, 0))%> ?

Comment: sorry yes... THANK YOU