# ASP Len() function returns Type Mismatch error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Below is my server side asp code of my classic ASP application:

```
Function isValidPACSSession()
...
Dim sessionID : sessionID = Request.QueryString("forSessionID")
isValidPACSSession = SessionID2PACSUserID(sessionID)
...
End Function

Function SessionID2PACSUserID(sSessionID)
if (Not IsNull(sSessionID) AND Len(sSessionID) > 0) then
            ...it fails here at the Len function.
        else
            ...
        end if
End Function
```

Len() function throws "Type Mismatch" error for this partcular instance, wheras other calls made to SessionID2PACSUserID() by other components are just fine. Please help.

Comment: If `Request.QueryString("forSessionID")` is null it will fail, make sure it isn't by this little trick `sessionID = Request.QueryString("forSessionID") & ""` or `Len(sSessionID & "")` *(personally prefer to do it when setting my variables)*. Bigger question is, why you passing sessionID as a querystring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Not IsNull in ASP Classic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254463/if-not-isnull-in-asp-classic)

Comment: this is the probelem, i have checked the debugger
Request.QueryString("forSessionID") has value of "F50DAA7A37494A51A0A157D917FACF891129" of String type. Still len() function throws Type Mismatch error.

Comment: How you debugging? Also, have you tried the suggestions regardless to see if it makes a difference? At least try it so it can be eliminated and we try something else, assumption can be a problem.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 to debug. And i have tried to test the code as you suggested by modifiying the SessionID2PACSUserID() function, but it still doesnt work. By the way, its all server side classic asp code.

Comment: Never known server-side debugging of Classic ASP to work in Visual Studio *(why I asked)*, unless your testing a local site perhaps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution.. Actually i had a local variable by the name "len" on the calle web page which was causing the len() to fail. Changed len variable name to nLength and Len() now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're just trying to check if a value is present, why not do something like:

```
dim sessionLength : sessionLength = 0
if (Not IsNull(sSessionID) AND sSessionID <> "") then
    sessionLength = Len( sSessionID )
```

I also agree with the above statement of the VS debugger not working very well with classic asp

Comment: thanks. but i also need the length of the string to use it for DB Query purpsose.